# DB2 database in Oracle SQL developer with SSL option

Tags: jdbc, db2, oracle-sqldeveloper, db2-luw, dashdb

Need help to connect DB2 on cloud with Oracle SQL developer.
I have configured SQL developer with third party JDBC to other DBs, but not work in DB2 with SSL option.

There have no option to set "sslConnection=true" in connection dialog. I have tried db2 type 2/4 jdbc drivers, that's same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle-SQL-Developer successfully lets me connect to Db2-on-cloud with SSL.

My version of Oracle-SQL-Developer is old 17.02 and yes that version seems to lack a GUI way to add connection attributes for Db2 connections . I will update this answer for version 19.02 later.

A workaround is:

- append the required property to the database name field.
  Example:  `BLUDB:sslConnection=true;` .  Depending on version, the GUI
  may misbehave , in which case do not try a connect or test at this
  time, but instead try SAVE and then close Oracle-SQL-Developer - to
  cause it to update its **connections.xml** file.
- The connection information is stored in file **connections.xml**
  which you can edit when Oracle-SQL-Developer is closed. The location
  of that file may depend on which operating-system you are using. For
  Linux it is in the .sqldeveloper tree off the home directory of the user running SQL-Devleoper
  .  First take a backup of that file before
  you change it.  Search for your newly created connection name. Look
  through the settings to find the `customUrl` for your Db2-on-cloud
  connection. You can edit it to look something like below:

  `<StringRefAddr addrType="customUrl">
  <Contents>
  jdbc:db2://dashdb-txn-sbox-***********.services.*****.bluemix.net:50001/BLUDB:sslConnection=true;
  </Contents>`

If you made changes, save the file, ***take another backup of the changed file (in case it gets overwritten next time)***, and restart SQL-Developer. Your connection should appear in the Connections pane, and the connect should succeed if you entered all other credentials and connection-parameters correctly. Works for me...